# javascript: access the item inside array of array

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I have a problem to access the item inside array of array.
I'm using the AngularJs framework and here is the code:

```
$scope.db.items4 = [];  
var newRow={
    ID:0,
    action1:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    action2:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    };

$scope.db.items4.push(newRow);

for (var j = 0; j < 50; j++){
   var lastRow=items4.length-1;
   var thatDay=ts.items[j].day;
   if(items4[lastRow].ID=="0"){
       items4[lastRow]=ts.items[j].ID;
       items4[lastRow].action1[thatDay]=ts.items[j].action1;
       items4[lastRow].action2[thatDay]=ts.items[j].action2;
   }else{
    if(items4[lastRow].ID==ts.items[j].ID && items4[lastRow].action2[thatDay]=="0") { 
       items4[lastRow].action1[thatDay]=ts.items[j].action1;
       items4[lastRow].action2[thatDay]=ts.items[j].action2;
        } else{
           var newRow2={
            ID:0,
            action1:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            action2:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
            };
            $scope.db.items4.push(newRow2);
            lastRow++;
            items4[lastRow]=ts.items[j].ID;
            items4[lastRow].action1[thatDay]=ts.items[j].action1;
            items4[lastRow].action2[thatDay]=ts.items[j].action2;
            }
        }
   }
```

When I run it, the javascript console always says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: items4 is not defined
```

But obviously items4 has been defined in the beginning; (  any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you cache `items4[lastRow]` you'll make that code 1000 times cleaner.

Comment: No, `items4` hasn't been defined, `$scope.db.items4` has been.

Comment: yeah, it looks like you have actually never defined items4...that would be something like `var items4 = $scope.db.items4;`

Comment: the irony is that you have typed items4 a million times and forgot to even define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna simplify it change the first line to be like this:

```
var item4 = $scope.db.items4 = [];
```

Comment: Thanks.I thought $scope.db.items4 means items4. Now there is no more "items4 is not defined " but the result is still not correct. Is items4[i].action2[j] the right way to access the element inside the array of array? thanks.

Comment: Well, you are overriding the items4[lastRow] with the ID value which i expect it to be a string or number value: >>
items4[lastRow]=ts.items[j].ID;
So now items4[lastRow] contains a string or number value of the ID and not the object. So calling item4[lastRow].action1 should throw an error.